# How to set id dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        a: 5
      };
  }

  onClick () {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= this.state.a;
  }

  render() {
    const { a } = this.state;

    return ( 

      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}> Click</button>
        <p id="test"></p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

https://codepen.io/milo-boyd/pen/vaxzOY

How can I make this code using dangerouslySetInnerHTML? I do not want to innerHTML. When I click on the button, it should write 5.

Comment: Why use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` at all? Just use `{}` in the JSX part.

Comment: Maybe you should repeat the react tutorial at [Making an interactive component](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#making-an-interactive-component).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your question but do you want something like this ?

```
class App extends React.Component {

 state = {
  a: null
 }

 onClick = ()=>{
  this.setState({a:5})
 }

 render() {
  const { a } = this.state;

  return (

  <div>
    <button onClick={this.onClick}> Click</button>
    <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:a}}></p>
  </div>
  )
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any point using dangerouslySetInnerHTML as pointed out by Quentin. You can just use set state:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
      this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      a: null // set initial value
    };
  }

  onClick () {
    this.setState({a: 5})
  }

  render() {
    const { a } = this.state;

    return ( 

      <div>
      <button onClick={this.onClick}> Click</button>
       <p id="test">{a}</p>
    </div>
    )
  }
}


React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

However, if you want to learn about dangerouslySetInnerHTML, then you can find an example [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You would need some kind of state variable to control whether or not `a` should be displayed or not. 
Below a working example:

I have added the variable `showA` which is a boolean and controls if `a` should be visible or not.

Then, inside your `<p>` you need to print your variable with `<p>{this.state.showA && a}</p>`.
This is a short-circuit evaluation and means that if `this.state.showA` is true, then return the value of `a`. Otherwise, return `false` which renders nothing in the DOM.

I also removed the `id="test"` as it is no longer needed.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
      this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        a: 5,
        showA: false
      };
  }
  
  onClick () {
    this.setState(prevState => ({showA: !prevState.showA}));
  }
  
  render() {
    const { a } = this.state;
    return (      
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}> Click</button>
        <p id="test">{this.state.showA && a}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```